Documentation for MSBuild Errors
Is there any documentation pertaining to specific MSBuild errors? I searched the web but couldn't locate anything.
I am looking for documentation that would explain what is the import of a specific MSBuild Error. For example, a previous post on SO pertains to the error code MSB3073, which has been explained as pertaining to heap corruption in the accepted answer:
error-msb3073-the-command-lib-tests-exe-vcend-exited-with-code
Appreciate your thoughts.
TIA
Vinod

In the MSBuild documentation in 'MSBuild Reference' -> 'Error Messages', some of the MSBuild error codes are documented.
(BTW MSB3073 does not mean heap corruption.)
If the error code is not documented, the source code for MSBuild is available in the dotnet/msbuild repo. You can search for the error code to find the string resource name.
e.g. From src/Tasks/Resources/Strings.resx#L396-L399:
  <data name="Exec.CommandFailed">
    <value>MSB3073: The command "{0}" exited with code {1}.</value>
    <comment>{StrBegin="MSB3073: "}</comment>
  </data>

The resource name for MSB3073 is Exec.CommandFailed.
Searching for the Exec.CommandFailed string shows that the resource is used in one place which is within the Exec task.
